# jQuery change events lost when updating html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jquery-events

I have a Rails application that has a displayed table of organizational leaders with a pair of radio buttons for each to indicate if they are 'Active' or 'Retired.' When a button is pressed, Ajax is used to save the state to the database and a success message (or failure message) is displayed that then fades away as programmed. However, while the first button change on any leader seems to work, subsequent change events on each leader are not detected. I've found several posts with problems similar to this, but none of the solutions in those seem to work reliably. I must be missing something.

The top level view contains the line below that identifies the `id` of the table cell for a particular leader and renders the cell from a partial.

```
<td id="status_<%= leader.id %>_cell"><%= render(:partial =>
  "connections/edit/leader_status", :locals => {
  :leader => leader, :display_response => "" } ) %>
</td>
```

The `id` above is passed through `data-update` as the element to be updated to jQuery. The partial `_leader_status.html.erb` contains:

```
<%= display_response.html_safe -%>

<%= radio_button_tag("status_#{leader.id}", 'Active', (leader.role == 'ActiveLeader'),
  :class => "leader_status", data: { url: url_for(action: :toggle_leader_status,
  id: leader.supporter.id ), update: "status_#{leader.id}_cell"}
) %> Active
<%= radio_button_tag("status_#{leader.id}", 'Retired', (leader.role == 'RetiredLeader'),
  :class => "leader_status", data: { url: url_for(action: :toggle_leader_status,
  id: leader.supporter.id ), update: "status_#{leader.id}_cell"}
) %> Retired
```

The controller code in `toggle_leader_status` that responds to re-render the status cell is:

```
render(:partial => "connections/edit/leader_status", :locals => {
  :leader => @entity.leader,
  :display_response => 
    "<div id='#{id}' class='#{klass}'>#{message}</div>" + 
    "<script type='text/javascript'>$('##{id}').fadeOut(#{duration})</script>"
})
```

And the jQuery code is:

```
<%# parameterized so only one copy is needed for all radio buttons %>
<script>
  $(function($) {
    $(".leader_status").change(function(){ 
      // get id of element to stuff response into
      var update_id = "#" + this.getAttribute('data-update'); 
      $.ajax(this.getAttribute('data-url'), {dataType: 'text'}).done(
        function(data) { $(update_id).html(data); } // problem part
      );
    })
  });
</script>
```

The first time I click a radio button that changes its state, the HTML of the page is updated correctly (verified through FireBug)--usually-- and display_response message is displayed and fades as expected. If I then click the alternate radio button nothing happens. However, on some occasions when I click a button everything seems to happen but the display of the button changes back to its prior state. If I replace the problem part:

```
$(update_id).html(data);
```

with

```
alert("An Event! " + data);
```

The alert happens every time. With the problem code, updating the table cell is blocking subsequent change events from happening. If I change:

```
$(".leader_status").change(function(){
```

to

```
 $(".leader_status").live('change', function(){
```

this works better, but still only, say, 90% of the time. If I use `.on` instead, it works maybe 10% of the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried with _`.on()`_ handler

Comment: If you read the last line in the post you'll see I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the event to one of the element's parents that does not change.

Like this:

```
$('table').on('change', '.leader_status', function(){

});
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I'm new to jQuery. I'd tried attaching to an element's parent in some way before but got it wrong because it hadn't worked.